# Force user to select item from autocomplete list

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to Force user to select item from autocomplete list.
I got the following code from a link.After implementing the below javascript functions   the autocomplte list does not appear.
If i remove calling the below javascipt  functions,the autocomplte list appears.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   var isItemSelected = false;
   //Handler for AutoCompleter OnClientItemSelected event
   function onItemSelected() {
       isItemSelected = true;
   }
   //Handler for textbox blur event
   function checkItemSelected(txtPCodebox) {
       if (!isItemSelected) {
           alert("Please select item from the list only!");
           txtPCodebox.focus();
       }
       else {
           //reset isItemSelected
           isItemSelected = false;
       }
   }
```

What is the problem i am not able to figure out.
    If there is any other method to to the same thing?Please help....

Comment: How are you initializing the autocomplete? And how are you calling these functions?

Comment: i am using webservice to call autocomplete.calling javascript functions like onblur="checkItemSelected(this) for textbox and OnClientItemSelected="onItemSelected() for autocomplete extender